# Is there a way to remove duplicate values in javascript without creating a second array to store the unique values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I have created this:

```
const arr = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6];

for (i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++){
  for (j = 0; j <= arr.length; j++){ 
   if(arr[i] === arr[j]){
     arr.splice(arr[i]  ,1)
   }
  }  
}

console.log(arr);
```

But I get the first value removed, and the rest works fine. Why is the first value removed?

Comment: let the j-loop start from i+1, saves time, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `Set` to achieve this.

```js
const unique = [...new Set([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6])];
/**
 * If you don't want to use the spread operator
 *
 * `Array.from(new Set([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]));`
 *
 * is also an option
 */ 
console.log(unique)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're passing the value instead of the index in the splice method.
try to print whatever is being removed, you'll get your answer and
here's the solution for that

```
   const arr = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6];

for (i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++){
  for (j = 0; j <= arr.length; j++){ 
   if(arr[i] === arr[j]){
     arr.splice(arr.indexOf(arr[i])  ,1)
   }
  }  
}

console.log(arr);
```

Goodluck :)

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the array whilst looping it.

A more modern approach is to use a [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let unique = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6]
  .reduce( (a, b) => 
    !a.find(v => v === b) ? [...a, b] : a, []);
console.log(unique);
```